# Is it possible to stream one's desktop to Youtube live event?

Tags: 13.10, youtube, video-streaming

The goal is to run the Live event, but not from one's webcam, but rather streaming the contents of the desktop. How would i go about doing that under Ubuntu GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Google hangouts, it's pretty simple, start an Hangout on air and share your Desktop.

The process to start a live hangout is well described here:

https://www.google.com/+/learnmore/hangouts/onair.html

Regarding desktop sharing (or just one application):

1. Hover over the left side of the video call window, and a bar with
   various app icons will appear.
2. Click [image] Screenshare on the left
   side of your screen.
3. In the window that appears, choose your desktop or choose the window
   you want to share.
4. Click Start Screenshare.

[Source](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1660627?hl=en)

Comment: Is there a way to while showing my desktop, also show my camera on the corner of the screen, on top of everything?

Comment: @BrunoFinger: I don't think it's possible out of the box, but solutions seem to exist, see https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/N9r465UDraA

Comment: What i've ended up doing is just what Sylvain Pineau has suggested, but at the same time i've made the Google Hangout visible to the empty group of people only, this creates live event on Youtube, which i then can advertise to whoever i want.

Comment: As of 2017, I don't believe this answer works anymore. You would need to use @Space ED's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

A good tool to use is Open Broadcasting Software, it is free and open source and has an easy install for Ubuntu [here](https://obsproject.com/download).

in OBS
settings > streaming has a place to put the streaming key and then you add your screen capture to sources. Then you can start streaming.

Once you have this going you can pick any audio device, camera, screen or window and combination thereof.

You can get a smaller window in the corner for that personal touch by right clicking the source and choosing transform then for example for bottom right corner.

**position 1364, 768

size 300,200

positional alignment bottom right**